# PHP get XML values, FOREACH create user and copy image. Whats wrong?

Tags: php, xml

So i have this cron.php to do some tasks every 15minutes.
Cron works fine, but something is wrong with my php code and i cant figure it out.

I want to copy the remote xml file to local folder (this works), then, parse thru the xml file and get all display_name and image_url values. Then, create local folder with username and copy its thumb there... how hard can this be? i've been at it for past 5 days :(

Can you help?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f

<?php

// Copy remote xml to local dir

copy ('http://www.remoteweb.com/api/?format=xml', '/includes/cache/feed.xml');


// connects to xml
$xmlor = '/includes/cache/feed.xml';
$doc = New DOMDocument();
$doc->load($xmlor);
// gets xml values as vars
$resource = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlor, null, true);

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('display_name') as $user ) {

// create dir with username
if (!file_exists('/includes/cache/_thumbs/'$user'')) {
    mkdir('/includes/cache/_thumbs/'$user'', 0755, true);
}

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('image_url') as $thumb ) {
// copy user thumb to user folder
copy ($thumb, '/includes/cache/_thumbs/'$user'');
                        }
                }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in the browser and checking for errors?

Comment: Also wont $user in your foreach be a simplexml object and not a string to be used as a folder name?

Comment: Why flag my question? i'm not a php coder, i'm just trying to learn something, i cant understand the negative atittude.
Regarding errors i'm aware of it, and i think i've fixed it, regarding the xml object would this do the trick in converting it into a string? 
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('display_name') as $user->nodeValue ) {
foreach( $ctb_user->childNodes as $user ) {
$ctb_user = $resource->display_name;

Comment: @PaulC. - I suspect one reason for the downvote might be because you've not explained what the problem is. When you run the code, what happens? Do you get any errors? If it doesn't do what you want, what does it do? If you can run this from the browser (or the command line, or redirect output from cron), you can see if you're getting any error messages. At the moment, your question is effectively some code and you saying "it doesn't work", without saying _how_ it doesn't work.

Comment: @andrewsi ty for your explanation, now i know how it works. :)

Comment: @PaulC. Don't worry about your questions being flagged it happens all the time, maybe consider how you could write it so it helps more people and is less generalized, or maybe explain what you did in those 5 long days of woe you went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Example:

```
<response>
<resource>
<display_name>Madsprings</display_name>
<image_url>https://serverexample.com/avatar/madsprings.jpg</image_url>
</resource>
</response>
```

**So i changed the code to this,**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/home/sgs/public_html/includes/cache/ctbfeed.xml");

foreach($user = $xml->xpath("//response//resource//display_name") as $ctb_user){
echo $ctb_user;

if (!file_exists('/includes/cache/_thumbs/' . $ctb_user)) {
    mkdir('/includes/cache/_thumbs/' . $ctb_user, 0755, true);
        }

foreach($thumb = $xml->xpath("//response//resource//image_url") as $thumb_url){
$path = parse_url($thumb_url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$local_thumb = basename($path);
copy ($thumb_url, ('/includes/cache/_thumbs/' . $ctb_user . '/' . $local_thumb));
        }
}
```

***And it appears to be working :)***

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors on lines 20, 21 and 26 related to the concatenation of `$user` and the single quoted strings.

To append the value of the variable `$user` to a string, use the following syntax:

```
'/includes/cache/_thumbs/' . $user
```

However this is probably not all that is wrong with your code. `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` which you are iterating with foreach. `$user` will be an object of type `DOMElement`. Concatenating it directly with a string will result in a fatal error "Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string".

So I suggest replacing the markup `'something'$user''` with:

```
'something' . $user->nodeValue
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply..
"So I suggest replacing the markup 'something'$user'' with:

'something' . $user->nodeValue"

Wich line? this one? 
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('display_name') as $user ) {